# In how many ways can we order a dozen two-scoop ice cream cones?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

An ice cream store sells $30$ different flavours of ice cream and it offers a
choice of $3$ different kinds of cones. In how many ways can we order a dozen
two-scoop ice cream cones if any two of them in one order must differ at least
by a flavour or by the kinds of cones?

Am I right to say we have $30$ choices for the first scoop and $29$ choices for the second and a dozen orders; thus, $30(29)(12) = 10440$?

Comment: We have 33 choices for 1st why 30 it can also differ in cones??

Comment: Where does 33 come from? @ArchisWelankar

Comment: You have (30)(29) ways of ordering two different scoops of ice cream, treating "chocolate on top and vanilla on bottom" as distinct from "vanilla on top and chocolate on bottom." But, for each of these, you have 3 different kinds of cones (I suppose "cake cone" and "sugar cone" and something else, the ice cream store I used to work in only had two kinds). Also, I think this asks you to further consider cones with two scoops of chocolate.

Comment: Once you distinguish the total number of distinct two-scoop ice cream cones, say $k$, then I think this problem wants you to find the number of ways of taking these $k$ and choosing 12 of them.

Comment: Michael we have 30 toppings and 3 types of cone s so cant the same toppings differ in cones??

Comment: Ignoring the cones and ignoring that you can have two scoops of the same flavor, you got that there are 30\*29 ways to make the first cone.  (It should be 3\*30\*30 but let's ignore that.)  You then multiplied that by 12?  Why?

Comment: (1). Can you have 2 of the same flavor for ice creams ?  
(2). And if the flavors are different, does vanilla-choco count as different from choco-vanilla ?

Answer (score 1):

So you've got 2scoop 30 toppings and 3 cones. That means 30 * 30 * 3 = 2700 different ice creams (as we can have an ice-cream with twice the same flavor).

And now pick 12 but don't let any one of them be the same. This latter one is thus a combination in which order doesn't matter. So 2700 choose 12. Combination rule:

$$\binom{2700}{12}=\frac{2700!}{2688!\times 12!}=3.05771e+32$$